# Why Java infinite loop is possible? And what recommendations for this

Tags: javascript, java, multithreading, sockets, infinite-loop

I'm new to Java, but not so to JavaScript.

So, in JS you can't use code like this

```
while(true){/* do something */}
```

Because this way browser tab will just get stuck forever. Actually it will be hard to close this tab after infinite loop was invoked.

But in Java, as I saw, it is normal to use code like this

```
try {
    while (true) {
        try {
            socket.println(data);
        } finally {
            socket.close();
        }
    }
} catch (IOException exception){
    log(exception);
}
```

Q1. So, I'm wondering how infinite loop works in Java?

Q2. If I want to listen socket for data for hours, does my Thread will get stuck as browser tab with JavaScript?

Q3. (if Q2 == false) Why Java infinite loop don't consume all of the available resources of Thread as we see in JavaScript?

Q4. Whether this variant of code is more appropriate for socket reading or not because I can miss some important data while "sleeping"?

```
while(true){
    readSocket();
    Thread.sleep(10);
}
```

Comment: Socket won't work that way, you need to accept the socket connection first

Comment: Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept(); in the while loop, make sure the while loop is in thread or doInBackground

Comment: what if my socket is actually a client, not a server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q1 - An infinite loop will repeat the code until interrupted somehow. In this case, it's actually not infinite - it uses a trick of a kind. It exists the loop when an exception in thrown.

Q2 - The thread does indeed get stuck in the loop. But in Java (and many other languages) you can just create another thread to run your UI or whatever you need to run at the same time.

Q3 - No, it uses the thread fully.

Q4 - Sleeping will not help you. When the thread is sleeping it just doesn't do anything, so it remains 'stuck'.

Answer (score 1):

Q1)  First to understand why this code is not an infinite loop, look at how exceptions work in java.  Whenever an exception happens in a try block, it immediately moves to the catch statement.  Thus, the socket will eventually close and then an exception will be thrown when the socket is accessed again.  The while loop will be exited and the error handler block will run.  So this is not an infinite loop.

Infinite loops in java work like any other programming language - if you don't have an exit condition, the code will simply not exit.

Q2) If you want to listen for data for a long period of time, there are a number of pre-built classes that handle this stuff for you.  Look into [Java ServerSocket](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html) and a number of related / derivative classes.

Q3) Not sure how to answer this, see above.

Q4) Again, see answer #2.  A lot of these problems are solved by using the builtin server methods.  If you don't want to use builtins, they serve as a good reference for building your own classes.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK the brower use a single thread for both:

- UI rendering
- JS execution

So it explained why browser stuck (I guess you mean the UI get stuck) when there is a infinity loop in the JS execution. For detail Checkout this [post](http://jessecravens.com/blog/2011/12/11/hack-82-web-wokers-basics-of-the-web-browsers-ui-thread/)

As for Java, most UI program are multi-threaded,

- GUI program. The update of UI is in another thread, so the GUI won't stuck when another thread is stuck.
- Web Server. Most java webserver will spawn a new thread (or use a thread pool) when handling incoming request, thus the accept loop won't stuck.

Further you may want to checkout the underlaying browser execution model: [Event Loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop)